# How to create a Dictionary in Python with 2 string keys to access an integer?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm very new to Python and I am trying to create a 2D dictionary that has 2 strings keys. One key will represent a starting location and the other an ending location. The return value needs to be an integer that represents the distance between those two cities.

For example if I have:

```
dict['New York']['Chicago']
```

I want to return the integer that represents the distance between those two cities.

I have parsed all the locations and distances from a text file, but I have no idea how to setup the dictionary values for each of those 3 components as I read each value.

Input is being received in the order: Start, Finish, Distance. Which is repeated until the end of the file is reached. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It seems fairly obvious that you want to read the `start, finish, distance` values, and store them as `distances[start][finish] = distance`.

Comment: Please share the data structure which is the result of you parsing the text file and the desired result dictionary for a concrete example.

Comment: @timgeb That is my question. How do I set up the dictionary in the first place with these values?

Comment: @LaneL I can show you that once you show me how your input data looks like after parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways to create this. First, the traditional `dict`

```
dic = {}
dic['New York'] = {}
dic['New York']['Chicago'] = 25
```

or using a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict
dic2 = defaultdict(dict)
dic2['New York']['Chicago'] = 25
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary whose keys are the starting points and whose values are dictionaries whose keys are destinations and whose values are the distances.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(dict)

for start, finish, distance in input_values:
    d[start][finish] = distance
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
dictionary = {}
for start, finish, distance in mylist:
    dictionary.setdefault(start, {})[finish] = distance
```

Using `dictionary.setdefault(start, {})` will return the value at index `start`.  If it doesn't exist, it creates one and puts it in that index.  We then make that dictionary at index `finish` to equal `distance`.